# Enable Excel "View Side by Side" and "Synchronous Scrolling"

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I created a C# program that opens 2 Excel worksheets Ex:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\test\test1.xlsx");
Process.Start(@"c:\test\test2.xlsx");
```

All I want to do after opening excel with these 2 sheets is enable the "View Side by Side" and "Synchronous Scrolling". These two options are under the View tab. I currently enable them manually, but would love to have that option enabled automatically. 
Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [automation from C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) to control the Excel application.

Create a reference to the Excel application and then open both workbooks.  From there it should be a simple matter of writing code like this to enable the "Side by Side" view:

```
Windows.CompareSideBySideWith "test1"
Windows.SyncScrollingSideBySide = True
```

Comment: I like your approach. How can I create a super simple excel reference. Sorry I am new to C#.

Comment: If you follow the link in my answer, there is a code sample that should demonstrate everything. Note that oXL variable references Excel itself and oWB references a workbook (in this case they are creating a new one, but you'd be opening an existing file). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into creating a Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) procedure that is run from within Excel.